# ITextSharp Quadpoints to Rectangle

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

How do I calculate or convert my quadpoints to a rectangle?

```
var quad = dic.Get(PdfName.QUADPOINTS) as PdfArray;
var rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(<missing conversion>);
var filter = new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect);
```

Well while waiting for an answer I found it myself. The Quadpoints array is always divisible by 8. A pair of x,y coordinates for each corner of the rectangle (2 * 4 = 8). With this information in mind I created the following extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static iTextSharp.text.Rectangle[] ToRectangle(this PdfArray quadricles)
    {
        var result = new List<iTextSharp.text.Rectangle>();

        for (var m = 0; m < quadricles.Size; m += 8)
        {
            var dimX = new List<float>();
            var dimY = new List<float>();

            for (var n = 0; n < 8; n += 2)
            {
                var x = quadricles[m + n] as PdfNumber;
                dimX.Add(x.FloatValue);
                var y = quadricles[m + n + 1] as PdfNumber;
                dimY.Add(y.FloatValue);
            }

            result.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(dimX.Min(), dimY.Min(), dimX.Max(), dimY.Max(), 1));
        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is only possible for very special quadpoints.

Comment: *Well while waiting for an answer I found it myself* - not really... quadrilaterals are based on any four points ordered counterclockwise. A `Rectangle`, on the other hand, must have its edges parallel to the x or y axis. Your code, therefore, only calculates the smallest `Rectangle` containing your quadrilateral.